# Как читать сообщения из канала telegram программно?

Tags: telegram

Есть публичный канал, нужно получать сообщения из него. Каким образом? pyTelegramBotAPI как я понял тут бессилен т.к. он может читать сообщения только из каналов куда его добавил админ

Answer (score 9):

Для таких целей придётся использовать клиентский API (Core API). Что это такое и базовое описание, можно прочитать [на официальном сайте Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api). А вот что касается документации, то, к сожалению, на оф.сайте она сильно устаревшая, благо нашлись добрые люди, которые создали и поддерживают актуальную [неофициальную документацию](https://schema.horner.tj).

Для работы с Core API есть готовые библиотеки, например, [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) для Python 3. В Readme на гитхабе есть примеры с авторизацией и получением файла сессии, я же покажу пример, как прочитать самое свежее сообщение в канале:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetMessagesRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest, ReadHistoryRequest
from telethon.utils import InputPeerChannel

api_id = 123456                  # API ID (получается при регистрации приложения на my.telegram.org)
api_hash = "abc123"              # API Hash (оттуда же)
phone_number = "+79161234567"    # Номер телефона аккаунта, с которого будет выполняться код


# Необходимо предварительно авторизоваться, чтобы был создан файл second_account,
# содержащий данные об аутентификации клиента.
client = TelegramClient('your_account', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()


username = 'telegram' # канал @telegram
dp = client.get_entity(username)

messages = client.get_message_history(dp, limit=1) # Получение одного сообщения
print(type(messages[1][0])) # Получение типа сообщения (в нашем случае - изображение)
print(messages[1][0].media.__dict__) # Словарь с информацией о медиафайле
```

Comment: а вы случайно не знаете как прочитать сообщение, и отметить его как прочитанное? т.е. что бы при следующем получении сообщений - оно не выдавалось как "не прочитанное".

Comment: Вопрос есть, а можно ли как то обойтись без юзернейма а использовать ник человека, ну или как он у меня записан?

Comment: @YDCdeveloper не понял Ваш вопрос, к сожалению

Comment: То есть, как мне их читать?
У меня почему-то при client.get_message_history(dp, limit=1) выдаётся ошибка что у client не может быть get_message_history. Телетон так же обновлял

Comment: @YDCdeveloper смотрите методы чтения диалога, не канала

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант парсить web версию телеграмма или окно приложения

Comment: Парсить веб версию? Там все на js и сокетах. Вся страница на них работает. Парсинг невозможен. Окно приложения тоже нереально парсить. Во-первых, как? Во-вторых, а если текст не влез на экран? Мне кажется  в API получше полазить надо (я его не знаю)

Comment: @Flippy, все это без проблем парсится. Главное использовать подходящий инструмент. для окон можно использовать например autoit, для веб тоже достаточно замечательных технологий

Answer (score -1):

Парсить можно при помощи апи и PHP, неплохой пример работы парсинга https://coderun.ru/telegram-populyarnye-obsuzhdeniya/

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте основное из содержимого по внешней ссылке прямо в Ваш ответ, иначе тут его, скорее всего, удалят. Спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

WEB-версия парсится на ура. После обновления t.me, не нужно искать ID последнего сообщения через API, все это уже можно глянуть через браузер.